# How te set the time for progress dialog

Tags: android, timeout, progressdialog

I have a big process called that will be called when I execute http-request and move to other activity or fragment,

The problem is, the process isn't finished yes then the display going to be blank and after that it move to another activity.

Question is, how we can set the timer and the timeout and where I can put the line code.

This is my current code

```
public class BigProccess extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        private Context mContext;
        ProgressDialog mProgress;
        private int mProgressDialog=0;

        public BigProccess(Context context, int progressDialog){
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mProgressDialog = progressDialog;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
          //  if (mProgressDialog== ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL){

                mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgress.setMax(100);
                mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                mProgress.setCancelable(false);
           // }

            mProgress.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          //  if (mProgressDialog== ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL){
                mProgress.setProgress(values[0]);
           // }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... values) {
            try {
                //This is to simulate there is a heavy process is running
                //and we make it slow down by 500 ms for each number
                for (int i =1; i<=10;i++){
                    publishProgress(i*10);
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
           // Toast.makeText(mContext,"Done!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

I've tried modified the thread.Sleep to 15000ms but it won't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not getting your question in terms of what you want and what happening now ? can you please explain it properly.

Comment: i need to set the timeout longer